# python django webapp packaging sdist

Tags: python, django, packaging, sdist

When I run `python setup.py sdist`
in my project directory and check the contents with `tar --list -f .\dist\my_project_name-1.0.tar.gz` I expected to see one important python file (`manage.py`) and a couple of directories such as `templates` which contains .html files, and `static` containing .css files. However, these files are all missing from the tar archive.

I've looked at many questions: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65958688/setuptools-sdist-package-directory-folder-name) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322050/python-setup-py-sdist-bdist-wheel) [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614086/how-does-setup-py-sdist-work) [Q4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691969/python-setuptools-sdist-installing-only-versioned-files)

but adding a `MANIFEST.in` or adding the following lines to my `setup.py`
didn't change anything. And what about my `manage.py`? Shouldn't python files be included by default with `sdist`?

```py
include_package_data=True,
data_files=[('templates','my_app/templates/my_app/*.html']),
            ('static', ['my_app/static/my_app/static/css/*.css'])]
```

Also, I get the same exact result with `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` (although I'm not sure what's the difference with the two commands).

Comment: No, all python files won't be included by default. The other important part of your `setup.py` is the `packages` and `py_modules` keywords. You must specify **all** packages _and_ subpackages and modules you want to include. Can you show the contents of your `MANIFEST.in` and full `setup.py` ? Repository layout may also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what about my manage.py? Shouldn't python files be included by default with sdist?

No, all python files won't be included by default. The other important part of your `setup.py` is the `packages` and `py_modules` keywords. You must specify **all** packages *and* subpackages and modules you want to include.

In general, Django apps aren't distributed with the manage.py file, but if you want to include it, you can add `py_modules=['manage']` to the setup keywords (assuming that `manage.py` is alongside `setup.py`).

To get your built distributions to contain data files, like your templates and static files, your `MANIFEST.in` needs to include them. You should add entries like these:

```
recursive-include my_app/templates *
recursive-include my_app/static *
```

The `data_files` keyword is not needed. Simply use `include_package_data=True` and it will respect your `MANIFEST.in`.

> Also, I get the same exact result with python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

`sdist` (source distribution) and `bdist_wheel` (wheel binary distribution) are just separate distribution formats.

So, compared to the first command, you're just telling it to build the source distribution AND a wheel. Adding `bdist_wheel` doesn't modify how the source distribution is built.